# How to add vertical line on side of sidebar?

Tags: beamer

I would like to have that gray vertical bar after my sidebar... How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the rule to the `sidebar left` template (change the color and thickness to suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\makeatletter
\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar left}
  {}
  {\smash{\hspace*{\beamer@sidebarwidth}\textcolor{gray!80}{\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}}}
\makeatother

\begin {document}

\section{Test section}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The theme is done :D Thanks a lot...
The final result is available here:
https://github.com/dnascimento/beamerLisbonTheme/blob/master/example.pdf?raw=true